# is there any way to access a site which is blocked from router?

Tags: windows, networking, router, blocking

I have 2 PC's named as PC A and PC B.  PC A can access to all sites but PC B has limited access. The router restricts to certains sites like youtube in PC B as its mac address is blocked in router.

Both PC A and PC B are in same network. Both has windows 8 OS and I know both admin credentials of both the machines.

Can I anybody please tell me how can I watch youtube from PC B via PC A?

I can not use teamviewer or remote support

Comment: You can set a proxy in PC A and let PC B go through the proxy. http://www.privoxy.org/

Comment: do I have to download the software or can I set proxy using windows built in apps.Please guide

Comment: you need to download the software.

Comment: @Chris.C isnt there any way to use proxy using windows built in apps?

Comment: Reset the configuration of the router so the sites are not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

you can connect both pc with ethernet cable and share the network of PC A in which you have internet acess to the ethernet network.
for doing that follow these steps

contorl panel -> network and internet -> network sharing center

whre you find the active networks. open that

goto propeties -> sharing -> check out 1st check box and select ethernet in drop down menu and then goto setting button below it and check all the services.
press ok it will allow ypur pc B to acess internet through pc A

Answer (score 0):

Better still, search on google for an application that can spoof your MAC address and have it change to something new. Your router is only blocking that MAC address so if you spoof a new one, it's likely your router will treat it without limitations. I don't have a specific Mac spoofing app I could recommend but there's a lot out there that exist. Just be sure to check for positive reviews and ratings before you download.

Comment: In the router they have mentioned certain mac address and mentioned mac addresss can access all sites. Not mentioned sites can not open youtube. So even if I change the mac address then also its of no use